# Member must have class/struct/union

Tags: c++, syntax

I am trying to write a *C++* class definition called `student.h` which will read the grades from the input file defined by the user, and write the grades into an output file 
defined by the user. This is what I have so far but I'm getting this error and I have no idea how to fix it. I was wondering if anyone could help me with this problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class student {
private: 
    int id; 
    int n;  // no of- grades
    int A[200]; // array to hold the grades
public: 
    student(void);              // constructor
    void READ(void);          // to read from a file to be prompted by user;
    void PRINT(void);      // to write into an output file
    void showStudent();   //show the three attributes
    void REVERSE_PRINT(void);      // to write into output file in reverse order;
    double GPA(void);           // interface to get the GPA
    double FAIL_NUMBER(void); //interface to get the number of fails
};



void student::READ()
{

    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;
            string fileName;
            cout << "Input the name of your file" << endl;
            cin >> fileName;
            inFile.open(fileName.c_str());
            if (inFile.fail()) {
                cout << fileName << "does not exist!" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                int x;
                inFile >> x;
                while (inFile.good()) 
                {
                    for(int i=0;i<200;i++)
                    {
                        A[i]=x;                 
                    }
                    inFile >> x;
                }
            inFile.close(); 
            }
}

int main()
{
     student a();
     a.READ();     //Line 56

}
```

This is the syntax that I get when I compile the code:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: New Project, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Main.cpp
1>c:\users\randy\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\new project\new project\main.cpp(56): error C2228: left of '.READ' must have class/struct/union
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: `student a();` - remove (), it should be just `student a;`

Comment: You do not need `(void)` all over the shop

Comment: It's a little unusual to have uppercase method names like READ().  Also you never set a student's id or number of grades.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what is called the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse):

```
student a();
         ^^
```

this is really a function declaration what you need is this:

```
student a;
```

or in *C++11* you can use [uniform initialization](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#uniform-init):

```
student a{};
```

The problem is there is an ambiguity in the *C++* grammar and so anything that can be interpreted as a function declaration will be. This is covered in section `6.8` *Ambiguity resolution* in the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf).

This is one of the cases where using a second compiler can help, `clang` actually spots the problem right away (*[live exmaple](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b7e33afdf65db8aa)*), the warnings given are as follows:

```
warning: empty parentheses interpreted as a function declaration [-Wvexing-parse]

 student a();
          ^~

note: remove parentheses to declare a variable

 student a();
          ^~
```

I cover pretty much all the online C++ compilers in my answer to [Online C++ compiler and evaluator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14652386/1708801) and I find instructive to run code in multiple compilers.

**Update**

Based on your comment, you will receive an error if you don't provide an implementation of your [default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor), this is one possible way to implement it but you need to decide what proper default values would be:

```
student::student() : id(-1), n(0) {}
```

Comment: No, this is not the most vexing parse.

Comment: @H2CO3 actually I asked Scott over email to clarify whether he considers this to fall under MVP and he said that he does. I know many on SO feel otherwise but after rereading that section in *Effective STL* I came away feeling it was actually another case of MVP and so I emailed and asked.

Comment: It's sad that the creator of the term (he's that, right?) is being inconsistent about his wording, causing confusion.

Comment: @H2CO3 there is very little online that even attempts to clarify what falls under MVP as far as I can tell *Effective STL* is the only authoritative public source. If you know of any material online that is authoritative and states otherwise let me know.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't (I am not especially a C++ guy, and C has significantly less of these quirks). I think I should just ask Scott as to *why* he is inconsistent and perhaps also ask him to *please* cease doing so... but that sounds like it's too much in finals time :D

Comment: Thank you for your input (and everyone else). I did what you said but then I got this error:{ Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall student::student(void)" (??0student@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main }. I then proceeded to comment out "student(void)" in class student and it worked.

Comment: @user3092755 that is because you did not provide an implementation for your default constructor `student::student`. My assumption was that you left out the implementation to keep the example short, let me update the answer.