# "Expression must be a pointer to a complete object type"

Tags: c++, visual-c++, matrix, vector, operator-overloading

I've tried browsing many of the other topics out there on this, but none of them seem to fix my specific problem.

I have a 3X3 matrix class and have the following code to allow the user to access the matrix's rows:

```
V3& M33::operator[](int i) 
{

  return rows[i]; // rows is a Vector3 array

}
```

Yet in my vector class when I try to do this:

```
void rotateAboutArbitraryAxis(int axis, float degrees)
{
    if(axis == 0)
    {
        M33 m();
        V3 row0(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        V3 row1(0.0f, cos(degrees), -sin(degrees));
        V3 row2(0.0f, sin(degrees), cos(degrees));


        m[0] = row0; //error
        m[1] = row1; //error
        m[2] = row2; //error

    }

}
```

There is an error flagged in the three marked places above.

The intellisense tells me "Expression must be a pointer to a complete object type"
while the actual build-error is "subscript requires array or pointer type."

Does anyone know why this is? I can provide more information if needed.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the [most vexing parse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529434/member-must-have-class-struct-union).

Comment: `M33 m();` --> `M33 m;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
    M33 m();
```

declares `m` to be a function that takes no arguments and returns a `M33`. That's crux of the [most vesting parse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20529468/434551).

Since the compiler thinks `m` is a function, it complains when you use it in the following lines:

```
    m[0] = row0; //error
    m[1] = row1; //error
    m[2] = row2; //error
```

As P0W commented, if you change the first line to:

```
    M33 m;
```

things should work as long as `M33` defines the `operator[]` function.