# What does this warning mean in orwell dev C++ IDE?

Tags: c++, warnings

I recently wrote below simple program but compiler shows warning.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int a();
    std::cout<<a;
    return 0;
}
```

> [Warning] the address of 'int a()' will always evaluate as 'true' [-Waddress]

What is the meaning of the above warning? Why value of a is 1 not 0?

Comment: `int a();` is a function declaration.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Comment: This is the [most vexing parse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529434/member-must-have-class-struct-union) ...  there is an ambiguity in the C++ grammar and so anything that can be interpreted as a function declaration will be.

Comment: @Shafik Technically this is not the most vexing parse, though it is related.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I asked Scott myself and he said he thinks of all the ambiguities as the most vexing parse. I had this discussion several times and so I just ended up emailing him and asking since he coined the term.

Comment: The question I linked above is not a perfect duplicate but it is close, I can not find a better one.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Is the behaviour of above program undefined? If yes then why?

Comment: @PravasiMeet: Why, over a year later, do you suddenly think it would be undefined? The warning literally tells you that you can _always_ expect a certain value here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It's an ODR violation for which no diagnostic is required, meaning that my code has UB. got my answer.

Comment: @PravasiMeet: Oh, you mean because of the missing definition and _odr-use_?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: exactly. right

Comment: @PravasiMeet: Okay :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int a();` declares a function, not a variable. If you want `a` to be a zero-initialised variable, then you'll need one of

```
int a{};  // C++11 or later
int a = int();
int a(0);
int a = 0;
```

`<<` doesn't have an overload that can directly take a function; so it looks for a suitable conversion sequence to a type that it is overloaded for, and finds:

```
int() -> int(*)() -> bool
```

that is, using the standard *function-to-pointer* and *pointer-to-boolean* conversions. The function pointer won't be null, since a declared function must exist and have an address; so the boolean value will be `true`.

Answer (score 3):

It might *look* like a definition of `a` as an `int`, but:

```
int a();
```

declares a *function* `a` taking no parameters and return `int`.

Use:

```
int a{};
```

instead.

```
std::cout<<a;
```

calls `operator<<()` with `bool` which is always nonzero, hence `true`.