# Why strange behaviour with operator()?

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-errors, operator-overloading

I have simple class,

```
class Func
{
public:
    Func()
    {
        cout<<"Constructor"<<endl;
    }

    int operator()(int)
    {
        cout<<"Operator ()";
        return 0;
    }
};
```

1. When I create it's object by giving parenthesis, `Func f();`, it prints nothing, it should print *Constructor*. But when I create object without parenthesis it prints *Constructor* which is expected. What is the different between these two?
2. When I try to use operator() `f(2)` it gives me compilation error.

> error C2660: 'f' : function does not take 1 arguments

Isn't it strange behaviour or I am missing something?

Comment: Because you declare `f` to be a *function* that takes no arguments and return a `Func` object.

Comment: [most vexing parse](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20529434/1708801)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Don't think it qualifies as "most" vexing. That's IMO reserved for something like `Foo f(Bar(), Baz());`

Comment: @T.C. I asked Scott about this and he said they are all the most vexing parse

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Scott Meyers?

Comment: Anyway, the more typical MVP comes along due to disambiguation rules; you have two alternative parses and one is picked over the another. In `Func f();`, there's no second parse. `()` is not permitted as an initializer there, by the grammar.

Comment: Expanding on TC's comment: the specification for initializer (as part of a declaration) is `( expression-list )`, and [syntax]/2 says that *X-list* means *one or more X's...*. This is covered by a different piece of grammar to expressions denoting temporary objects, which has `( expression-list opt )` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Func f();, it prints nothing, it should print Constructor

That is not true whatsoever.

Here is how you create a `Func`:

```
Func f;
```

> When I try to use operator() f(2) it gives me compilation error. error C2660: 'f' : function does not take 1 arguments. Isn't it strange behaviour or I am missing something?

Yes, it's strange, but it's not unexpected. When you wrote `Func f()` you declared a function called `f` returning a `Func`. Everything you try to do with `f` after that is, naturally, broken.

Comment: But when I have one argument constructor it works.

Comment: @PranitKothari: 100% unrelated.

Comment: But why? Should it make that big different for 0 args and 1 arg.

Comment: @PranitKothari If you actually want to declare a function returning a `Func` and taking no arguments, what would you write?

Comment: @T.C. Got your point.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit interesting here.

```
Func f();
```

is a forward declaration for a function, which takes no argument and return Func type object.

Check the below code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Func
{
public:
    int operator()(int)
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

int main ()
{
    Func f();
    f();
    return 0;
}

Func f ()
{
    cout << "My Func" << endl;
    Func * f = new Func;
    return *f;
}
```

It will output "My Func" on stdout.

Comment: `f` the function has a memory leak.

Comment: Yes, I have just mention this to illustrate the issue.

Comment: @AbhishekMittal: Regardless, you're teaching a broken function.