# Unresolved externals with inline constructor

Tags: c++

I have a simple 2 dimensional vector class, which is implemented as inline functions/operators.

However when I want to instantiate my Vector with no parameters I get Unresolved externals error and I'm not sure why. However, when I use other constructor with parameters it's ok.

This is my class:

```
class Vector2
{
public:
   float x;
   float y;

public:
   //Constructors
   Vector2() : x(0.0f), y(0.0f) {}
   Vector2(const float _x, const float _y) : x(_x), y(_y) { }
};
```

Creating instance which causes error:

```
Vector2 a();
```

But when instantiating with other constructor it's ok. This also works:

```
Vector2 a = Vector2();
```

I'm getting this:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class GreenEye::Maths::Vector2 __cdecl a(void)" (?a@@YA?AVVector2@Maths@GreenEye@@XZ) referenced in function main
1>X:\Development\Projects\Engine\x64\Debug\Test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved external
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Missing semi-colon `;` after final brace of class declaration. Other than that, I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: Edited, forgot to add it here in code, anyway that's not an issue

Comment: Exact error message please, or it didn't happen.

Comment: Cannot reproduce when adding the missing semi-colon too, as with @bku_drytt.

Comment: N.B. Functions defined in the class body are implicitly inline, so saying `inline` on them is redundant. The semi-colons after the function bodies are redundant too.

Comment: `Vector2 a();` is a declaration of a function named `a` that takes no arguments and returns a `Vector2` instance by value. Look up "most vexing parse".

Comment: Oh, obviously. Thank you.

Comment: @Praetorian: Except it's not the most vexing parse.

Comment: @Lightness [Maybe, maybe not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598673/why-strange-behaviour-with-operator#comment45503661_28598673).

Comment: @Praetorian: Nope, just the "not". Scott is wrong. TC (and me) are right. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you are not instantiating an object using the following:

```
Vector2 a();
```

This is actually a function declaration which is why it's complaining about the missing function at link time.

To create an object using the default constructor it should be:

```
 Vector2 a;
```

Comment: This problem is common enough to have a name: the most vexing parse.