# Destructor not called for default and deleted constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I've been playing around and got curious with this following code.

```
struct Bar {
    Bar()=delete;
    ~Bar() { std::cout << "dtor" << std::endl; }
};

struct Foo {
    Foo(){}
    ~Foo() { std::cout << "dtor" << std::endl; }
};

Bar b(); // (A) doesn't call dtor 
Foo f(); // (B) doesn't call dtor

Foo f;   // (C) calls dtor
Bar b;   // (D) error: use of deleted function 'Bar::Bar()'
```

**QUESTIONS**

1. Why the destructor is not called for both (A) and (B)?
2. Is there some magic with `()`?

Comment: Your top two declarations don't call a constructor either, because they're not constructing an object: they're declaring a function

Comment: I'm certain there are 100 duplicates but I can't find anything at the moment, gimme a sec

Comment: Yes, `()` is magic. in the sense that It means different things in different contexts. The de-magicisation rule is that if the compiler can interpret the expression as a function prototype, it shall.

Comment: Maybe a better dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529434/member-must-have-class-struct-union

Comment: I'm amazed there isn't an easy to find canonical

Comment: Yeah I know, I had to write the faulty code to find the error it gives and look up most vexing pass, which who would know to look it up...

Comment: new term for today "most vexing parse". thanks everyone!